Why PathGeometry draw an overlapped small line segment unproportionally?
Could someone help me with an issue of using PathGeometry?
When I draw a geometry that contains a small overlapped line segment, it was drawn longer than expected. Any idea on why and how to fix it? Thank you!
points are: (0,0) (0, 10) (0, 10.1) (0,10) (10,10) (10, 0)
code and result:
var figure = new PathFigure();
var segment = new PolyLineSegment();

Point point = new Point(0, 0);
segment.Points.Add(point);
**point = new Point(0, 10);
segment.Points.Add(point);
point = new Point(0, 10.1);
segment.Points.Add(point);
point = new Point(0, 10);
segment.Points.Add(point);**
point = new Point(10, 10);
segment.Points.Add(point);
point = new Point(10, 0);
segment.Points.Add(point);
figure.Segments.Add(segment);

if (segment.Points.Count > 0)
   figure.StartPoint = segment.Points[0];
figure.IsClosed = true;
pathGeom.Figures.Add(figure);


If adding another line segment with points (0, 11) (10, 11), you can see point (0,11) is on top of the point (0, 10.1) in above geometry.
Code and result:
var figure2 = new PathFigure();
var segment2 = new PolyLineSegment();

point = new Point(0, 11);
segment2.Points.Add(point);
point = new Point(10, 11);
segment2.Points.Add(point);
figure2.Segments.Add(segment2);

if (segment2.Points.Count > 0)
   figure2.StartPoint = segment2.Points[0];
figure2.IsClosed = false;
pathGeom.Figures.Add(figure2);



I think you should scale the whole thing up by 10; and do any "rescaling" afterwards. You're asking the system to scale "up" from .1 of a pixel.
